# Fedora 23 gdb core dumps with python2.7 in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, gdb

Running GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.10.1-31.fc23. 
Having gdb core dump is a little unnerving:

```
> gdb
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123   
      raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The core goes away if PYTHONPATH is erased before running gdb. But the program I'm running requires Python2.7 [embedded](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html). Without the PYTHONPATH settings the code I'm debugging is DOA.

Is there a way to start gdb with a PYTHONPATH that might have things that gdb does not like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `PYTHONPATH` environment value that will be passed to the target process (when it's created and run by `start`, `run`, etc.) by using either of these gdb commands:

- `set environment PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
- `set exec-wrapper env 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'`

This will affect only the target process's environment; it won't affect gdb's embedded python interpreter nor any process created using gdb's `shell` command.